# How to have rumble support in Mupen64Plus?

Tags: controllers, emulation, nintendo-64, ouya

Since the native OUYA controllers unfortunately lack force feedback, I'd like to buy either a wired or wireless XBOX360 or PS3 controller (or any other that I can then use on both the OUYA and my PC). But before I waste money on something that costs me my summer vacation to get working (if it's possible at all), I'd like to know:

- Which controllers (wireless or not) do connect to the OUYA without much of a hassle? It is not necessary that they work as OUYA-controller as long as Mupen64Plus (and preferably the other emulators available in the OUYA store) supports them. *I know this point makes the question rather broad, so please disregard it if you object, but consider the following still*
- How to setup Mupen64Plus with a controller that provides force feedback such that the N64 rumble functions are available? (Maybe this part is trivial once you got a fitting controller working, in which case I'll accept a simple "My [such-and-such] controller worked fine by using the setting [rumble-on]")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is old but I did find an answer so ...
According to [Mupen64plus Bug Tracker](https://github.com/mupen64plus-ae/mupen64plus-ae/issues/76) OUYA's response to their initial submission is "there is no vibration support".

Comment: Thanks, sounds about right. My OUYA's collecting dust anyway...